# Overriding inline css on iframe instagram widget not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, instagram

Usually when I want to override some css in an iframe, I'll just make sure it is more specific or use !important and have never had any issues until now. I am trying to embed my latest 4 instagram photos and I don't want the photos to have any space in between them. AKA I need to remove the margin on the anchor tags inside the iframe. I have tried making it specific and using !important. I also tried using jquery to wait until the iframe loads and insert inline css. Both methods will work on the iframe tag but not on anything inside it.

My site: http://chrisandlenzi.com/ and the instagram feed is toward the bottom of the page. I have this in my css file right now:

```
.media-grid li a {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

This is the jquery that I was trying:

```
    $('iframe').load( function() {
        $( '.no-border' ).each(function () {
            this.style.setProperty( 'margin', '0px', 'important' );
        });
    });
```

If anybody can help me figure out how to do this that would be great, but if you at least know why this is happening, that works, too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was using the http://widget.websta.me widget and no matter what I tried, including Andrew Lyndem's answer, nothing worked. I just switched widgets and am now using this widget instead http://snapwidget.com/ and as long as I choose the responsive option, the "photo padding" setting works. When I did not check the responsive setting, it gives me 5px no matter what I put in there. I still have no clue why, but here is the fix, in case anybody else is having the same issue.